# broadcast receiver not worked when device is lock(sleep)

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

when i lock the phone it will not call api.... 
but when phone is not locked its working perfectly.......

In my **startActivity**.

```
public void startUserService()
    {
        try
        {
             PowerManager.WakeLock wl;
             PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
            wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK, "ROMS Lock");
            wl.acquire();
            Intent intent = new Intent(Start_Activity.this, PermitService.class);
            intent.putExtra("start", true);
            PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(Start_Activity.this, 0, intent, 0);
            AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE); //Constant.serviceTime
            alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() + 500, 20000, pintent);
            isServiceRunning = true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

and my **BroadCastReceiver**

```
public class PermitService extends BroadcastReceiver
{

    Context mContext;
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        mContext=context;
        if (intent != null && intent.getBooleanExtra("start", false))
        {
            if (new Validations(mContext).Connection_Check())
            {
                Toast.makeText(context, "User Service called ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                setRequest();
            }
        }

    }

    @SuppressLint("ShowToast")
    public void setRequest()
    {

        StringListener objStringListner = new StringListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(String arg0)
            {
                if (arg0.length() > 0)
                {
                    int code = Integer.parseInt(arg0);
                    if (code != 0)
                    {
                        //error message
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        SharedPreferences pref = mContext.getSharedPreferences(Constant.PREF_APP, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        ContentValues param = new ContentValues();
        param.put("UserType", pref.getInt("UserType", 0));
        param.put("UserId", pref.getInt("UserId", 0));
        MRequest objRequest = General_Class.checkUserAuth(Method.POST, param, "UpdateCheckLogin", objStringListner, mContext);
        MRequestQueue objRequestQueue = new MRequestQueue(mContext);
        objRequestQueue.add(objRequest);
    }

}
```

**Note:**
I have checked in tablet and mobile, same code is work for mobile, but its not work in tablets(micromax,iball).

Comment: [Check this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.WakeLock.html)

Comment: @ByzantineFailure not worked.

Comment: Update some code -- where do you find problem in the power manager? Also double check your activity lifeCycle methods.

Comment: i have check n number of times.... whenever i lock screen then its not  work..... i really don't know what is the issue.

Comment: Microsoft tablet 4.0.4?!?!!

Comment: Micromax tablet and os is 4.0.4